# How to group contours and draw a single bounding rectangle

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, contour

I need to group `contours` and draw a single `bounding rectangle` that encloses all the contours, something like this

[image]

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import cv2 as cv

img = cv.imread('shapes1.png', 0)
imgRGB = cv.cvtColor(img.copy(), cv.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)

_, ctrs, _ = cv.findContours(img, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

boxes = []
for ctr in ctrs:
    x, y, w, h = cv.boundingRect(ctr)
    boxes.append([x, y, w, h])

for box in boxes:
    top_left     = (box[0], box[1])
    bottom_right = (box[0] + box[2], box[1] + box[3])
    cv.rectangle(imgRGB, top_left, bottom_right, (0,255,0), 2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10, 10))
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(imgRGB, cmap='gray')
```

[image]

Is there any straight forward way to do it rather than merging all bounding rectangles programmatically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't mind using `numpy`, you can simply use the [`concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html) function from there, see the following code. Attention: I use OpenCV 4.0.0 where the order of the return values of [`findContours`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0) is different.

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# Input image
input = cv2.imread('images/kchZb.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Modify input image to extract "original" image
_, input = cv2.threshold(input[10:400, 40:580], 224, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find contours
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(input, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Concatenate all contours
cnts = np.concatenate(cnts)

# Determine and draw bounding rectangle
x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(cnts)
cv2.rectangle(input, (x, y), (x + w - 1, y + h - 1), 255, 2)

# Output image
cv2.imwrite('images/output.png', input)
cv2.imshow('Input', input)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

[image: Output]

Disclaimer: I'm new to Python in general, and specially to the Python API of OpenCV (C++ for the win). Comments, improvements, highlighting Python no-gos are highly welcome!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by iterating all the contours and create a bounding box from each contour and then calculate the **minX, minY, maxX, maxY**.

```
int minX=MAX_INTEGER, minY=MAX_INTEGER, maxX=0, maxY=0;

for each contour in contours:
    Rect rect = boundRecFromContour(contour)
    if rect.x < minX:
        minx = rect.x
    if rect.y < minY:
        minY = rect.y
    if rect.x+rect.width > maxX:
        maxX = rect.x+rect.width
    if rect.y+rect.height > maxY:
        maxY = rect.y+rect.height
Rect groupRect = (minX, minY, minX+maxX, minY+maxY)
```

Now you can draw the `groupRect`.

Also, you can use the technic as well to achieve the problem:

```
cv::Mat idx;
cv::findNonZero(binaryImg, idx);
// find min max points
double maxX = 0, minX = MAX_INTEGER;
double maxY = 0, minY = MAX_INTEGER;
for (int i=0; i<idx.rows; ++i) {
    cv::Point pnt = idx.at<cv::Point>(i);
    if (pnt.x > maxX) {
        maxX = pnt.x;
    }
    if (pnt.x < minX) {
        minX = pnt.x;
    }
    if (pnt.y > maxY) {
        maxY = pnt.y;
    }
    if (pnt.y < minY) {
        minY = pnt.y;
    }
}
Rect groupRect = cv::Rect(cv::Point(int(minX), int(minY)), cv::Point(int(maxX), int(maxY)));
```

Comment: I guess, that is exactly, what the questioner wanted to avoid by stating: _Is there any straight forward way to do it rather than merging all bounding rectangles programmatically_.

Answer (score 1):

@HansHirse solution was very elegant. Here is another solution, using enclosing of the bounding rectangles. This is possible directly with the Rect class in OpenCV in C++, and with the [OpenCV Wrapper library](https://github.com/anbergem/opencv_wrapper).

The or (|) operator is used to give the minimum enclosing rectangle.

```py
import cv2 as cv
import opencv_wrapper as cvw

img = cv.imread("shapes1.png", 0)
imgRGB = cvw.gray2bgr(img)

contours = cvw.find_external_contours(img)

enclosing_rect = contours[0].bounding_rect | contours[1].bounding_rect
enclosing_rect = enclosing_rect | contours[2].bounding_rect

cvw.rectangle(imgRGB, enclosing_rect, cvw.Color.GREEN)

cv.imshow("Image", imgRGB)
cvw.wait_key(0)
```

Disclosure: I'm the author of OpenCV Wrapper